# jquery Sortable not working, but jsfiddle does

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to get a table to sort the rows, but it won't work. When I try to drag a table row, nothing happens. It must be simple because it works correctly in jsfiddle, but not on a basic HTML page. Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wba5yko3/

Here is the html Page's code where is won't work:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>    
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("tbody").sortable();
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-spacing: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }
        td {
            width: 50px;
            height: 25px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>  
    <tbody>    
</table>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use https everywhere where it's possible

Comment: Also switch to html5 doctype ;)

Comment: @Endless You should elaborate as to why. Since you didn't, I will. He means you should include your external scripts via https. If your html page runs over https, but you include the scripts over http, you run into security risks.

Comment: thanks @RayfenWindspear. Http should be fine loading resources from https

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are selecting the element before it is ready. The fiddle runs on window.onload.

Either move the script to the bottom of the page so it is after your element or wrap it in document ready.

```
$( function () {
    $("tbody").sortable();
});
```